# OpenVPN Client Routing in External File

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have about 10 different VPN servers I connect to via the OpenVPN client.

I have a list of about 70-80 IP addresses that I want to not run through the VPN. I have set them up as route commands in each of the opvn configuration files.

This is quite a tedious solution as anytime I need to add or modify one of those IP addresses then I have to modify 10 different opvn files.

Is there a way to have a single external file which contains all my routing commands which I manage, and just have a single command in each of the opvn files that tell them where the routing commands are?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I also used openvpn like you before, with some statics routes set into the ovpn configurations files. I never find a way to set as a static file so I made a script wrote in python with jinja template that automate the configuration. The idea was to retrieve the user information from the LDAP and after that generate the authorized routes from a database (simply an sqlite).

Now from a new version of our vpn server, we use the "push" route of openvpn server with some specifics profiles.

Hope this will help you,
Regards,

Comment: Thanks. Creating a script to inject the routes might be a quick way but surprised there's nothing inbuilt for this considering you can use external files in your opvn file for many other options.

Unfortunately I do not control the servers so I cannot use the push route.